# Inside mongodb shell how to retrieve next results?

Tags: mongodb

In mongodb shell, I would like to retrieve the next elements for a query.

```
cursor = db.collection.find({ok: true});
```

Now, I see 20 results.

I would like to see the next results.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Reference: [mongodb.org](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Overview+-+The+MongoDB+Interactive+Shell)

After the find, just run: `it`

Note you can increase the batch size, e.g.

```
DBQuery.shellBatchSize = 100
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also just skip the first set of results:

```
db.collection.find({ok: true}).skip(20)
```

This is useful whatever the shellBatchSize setting.